# Getter and Setter, static and array

Tags: php, arrays, static-methods

i have an error class like this:

```
class Error{

    private static $_errors =[];

    public static function getError()
    {
        return self::$_errors;
    }


    public static function setError($fields, $messages)
    {
       self::$_errors[$fields] = "$messages ";
    }
}
```

then i have another file to access this getter and setter like this:

```
public function required($fields= array())
{
    foreach($fields as $value) {
        if (isset($this->_input[$value])) {
            if (empty($this->clean($this->_input[$value]))) {
                $name = self::changename($value);
                $messages = "$name is required.";
                error::setError($value, $messages);
            }
        } else{
            $name = self::changename($value);
            $messages = "$name not found.";
            error::setError($value, $messages);
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to print the error messages like this:

```
if (!empty(error::getError())) {
    foreach (error::getError() as $error) {
        echo "<li>$error</li>";
    }
}
```

i got "Warning: Illegal string offset." which one of my code causing this problem? and how i should fix it?

Comment: it's in a different class

Comment: on which line does this warning appear?

Comment: it's error when i was trying to echo the error messages in this code it's the echo.

Comment: Any error reported by the PHP interpreter contains the path of the file and the line where it happened.

Comment: it seem it's        self::$_errors[$filed] = "$messages"; that cause an errors.

Comment: Try to dump error:getError()

Comment: when i use print_r it give me this array array(5) {
  ["maxfiles"]=>
  string(2) "20"
  ["postmax"]=>
  int(8388608)
  ["displaymax"]=>
  string(6) "8.0 MB"
  ["tokenForm"]=>
  string(32) "bdd5a7c595ed5e2ae3b6f5e4c000e86b"
  ["waktuTokenForm"]=>
  int(1421922009)
}

Comment: it show right array so i think the error is in my echo.

Comment: `error::setError()` or `Error::setError()` ?

Comment: i think it's not about typo, because i use php gui that can check if make a typo. if it's wrong here it's because i write and translate some code into english so anyone can understand the code.

Comment: Okay. Could you take the output of `error::getError()` inside a variable and pass it in the foreach (Do a dump of that variable before passing and post the output here)? I don't think it's a necessity but for the sake of debugging.

Comment: here it is: Array
(
    [Nama Depan] => Nama Depan is required.
    [Nama Belakang] => Nama Belakang is required.
    [Username] => Username is required.
    [Password] => Password is required.
    [Verifikasi Password] => Verifikasi Password is required.
    [Email] => Email is required.
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is simple, i just use **is_array** because it seem my `$fields` contains is array. and if it's not it put in individual.

```
foreach($field as $value) {
  if (isset($this->_input[$value])) {

    if (empty(Security::clean($this->_input[$value]))) {
      $messages = "is Required.";
      error::inputError($value, $messages);
     }
  } else{
     $messages = "Tidak ditemukan.";
     error::inputError($field, $messages);

  }
}
```